# How to prevent deadlock in the marklogic trigger

Tags: collections, triggers, marklogic

How to prevent deadlock in the marklogic trigger.
Triggers are using collection.

Comment: The question is too broad and too vague. Provide more detail if you want any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

mblakele Is right,

However deadlocks normally happen because you are writing to a file that needs to be read or your reading a file that has a write lock on it.

So I would start by looking at how you are saving your files. You might want to isolate your savings from your reads.